# Retrieiving ValueError: Must specify 'validation_steps' to perform validation when doing step-wise training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have the following which works fine google colab, however when I run the same code using docker containers it throws an error

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32') 
X_test = X_test.astype('float32') 
X_train = X_train / 255.0 
X_test = X_test / 255.0
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train) 
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test) 
num_classes = y_test.shape[1]

batch_size = 64
steps_per_epoch = len(X_train) / batch_size

results = model.fit(X_train, y_train,batch_size = batch_size,
                             epochs = 500,
                             steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,  # data_size/batch size
                             validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

Retrieiving the following error trace

```
line 129, in <module>
validation_data=(X_test,y_test)
File /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py, line 1239 in fit
File /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py, line 88 in fit_loop
raise ValueError('Must specify 'validation_steps'

ValueError: Must specify 'validation_steps' to perform validation when doing step-wise training.
```

Comment: What model architecture have you used before fitting the data into that model?